# Data mining methods

Tags: classification, regression, analytics, data-mining

I would like to know which data mining methods (regression, assosiation, clustring or classification) I have to use in case if I would like to find the highest number of reviews among several apps categories.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: This question will not merit any reasonable answer as it's unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: If you wish to classify reviews as those expressing positive/negative sentiment, then you need to treat it is a `Classification` problem, which is part of `supervised` learning. `Regression` / `Random Forest` / `neural networks` etc are just tools to solve these `classification`/`clustering` class of problems. You are confusing the two things. First, you need to determine as to what your objective is and then phrase a proper statement as to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

None.

Finding the maximum is not data mining. It's a simple for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is the task of dividing the population or data points into a number of groups such that data points in the same groups are more similar to other data points in the same group than those in other groups. In simple words, the aim is to segregate groups with similar traits and assign them into clusters.